# Dynamically added table in asp.net not clearing styles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table who's rows are added dynamically in the code behind. The table sits inside an update panel:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlPR">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table ID="tblPR" runat="server">
            </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I do a tblPR.Rows.Clear() in the code behind, the table draws itself up again correctly but it appears that the formatting that was applied to the row in that position before the redraw is still applied to the cell which is incorrect. Any idea why this is happening?

I have tried making the UpdatePanel updatemode conditional and doing a upnlPR.Update() after clearing the rows but this problem persists. Particular problems being: Styles applied to cell in that row number / cell position still applied, column span of the cell in that row number / cell position still applied.

Thanks!

(asp.Net, C#)

To style the cells `cell.CssClass = competencyAchievementView.ManagerScore > competencyAchievementView.UserScore
                                                                            ? "manWorseScore"
                                                                            : "manBetterScore";`

Comment: Which formatting are you talking about ?

Comment: Can you show us how you Style the items?

Comment: Added the code to style into the question

Comment: @Bartdude: I'm talking about background colours of cells and colspan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should simply delete the row or the whole table control and add it back to the page. The clear() function is intended to remove content, not styling. 
But maybe you could also, in your binding (maybe it could help to show us this too), simply initialize it ? I mean if I understand well , you have also a third possibility (no style) besides classes manWorseScore and manBetterScore, right ?

Comment: if I say  tblPR = new Table(); it then just never adds rows to the table. Very odd.

Comment: I eventually iterated through each row and did a tblPR.Rows.RemoveAt(i)... Thanks. I thought that the Rows.Clear() would achieve the same thing